# Error building C# console application on Mac

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build a C# console application to run on my Mac, but when I try and build the following:

```cs
using System;

namespace DemoApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Hello World");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.307/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(20,20): Error MSB4092: An unexpected token ")" was found at character position 384 in condition "'$(_SelfContainedWasSpecified)' != 'true' and
                   '$(_CommandLineDefinedRuntimeIdentifier)' == 'true' and
                   '$(RuntimeIdentifier)' != '' and
                   '$(PublishAot)' != 'true' and
                   '$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETCoreApp' and
                   '$([MSBuild]::VersionGreaterThanOrEquals($(TargetFrameworkVersion'), '6.0'))". (MSB4092) (DemoApplication)
```

I'm brand new to C# and the .NET ecosystem, so would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction to fix this so that I am able to build my first 'Hello World'.

I've tried searching for the error code, but with no success.

Visual Studio for Mac: 17.6.3 (build 421)
Mac OS: Ventura 13.5

Edit: I think this came about after trying to use VS Code to build C# apps, and installing the C# extensions into VS Code.

I've been playing with Maui to build cross platform apps, and now I can't build any of those either - get the same error.

Edit:

DemoApplication.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: the problem is with wrong quoting on the last line: `'$([MSBuild]::VersionGreaterThanOrEquals($(TargetFrameworkVersion'), '6.0'))"`

Comment: Can you add the contents of the file `DemoApplication.csproj` ?

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: @MohammadMostafaDastjerdi - I've tried to fix the quoting; `'$([MSBuild]::VersionGreaterThanOrEquals($(TargetFrameworkVersion), '6.0'))'"` and now I get the following error: ```/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.307/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(20,20): Error MSB4092: An unexpected token "6.0" was found at character position 387 in condition...```

Comment: When you do `dotnet build` from the directory containing the `DemoApplication.csproj` file, will it also throw an error ?

Comment: Yes, same error

Comment: Trying to uninstall .net SDK's and start afresh using the .net uninstall tool, but get the following error: ```“dotnet-core-uninstall” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software. This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for more information. ```

Comment: You can download the latest (currently 7.0.400) from: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

Comment: Version 7.0.400 is only compatible with VS for Mac 17.7 but only 17.6.3 is available for download... so will have to wait for VS for Mac 17.7, however, after installing 7.0.400 I can now build and run the console app from the command line, so thanks for you help on this.